# $|f(x)|^2$ in the definition of Hilbert Space

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In the definition of the Hilbert space, it says it consists of all the vectors that are norm-square integrable, or

$$
\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty.
$$

However, I'm unsure if the $|f(x)|^2$ is computed by the inner product of the Hilbert space

$$
<f|g> = \int_a^b f(x)^* g(x)  dx
$$

or if it's simply squared.

I think the confusion stems from the norm also being written as $|f(x)|^2$ which is computed by taking the inner product with itself $<f|f>$.

Comment: It‘s the same thing. You use the fact that an inner product induces a norm.

Comment: @LukasKofler Thank you. Just to be entirely sure you mean that if $f(x)=x$ is a function in Hilbert space, then $|f(x)|^2 = \int_a^b x x dx = \frac{1}{3} (-a^3 + b^3)$ and **not** $x^2$?